# Pandas create new category based on position-column without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One of my columns indicates the x-distance of a person looks like this:

```
x_distance = [0.01, 0.321, 2.576, 0.41, 2.11, 2.62]
```

I want to create a column, that creates a new category, if there is a value in x_distance greater than 2.5 without using a for-loop (pay attention to the order of x_distance)
For x_distance the right answer would be:

```
x_distance_groups = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a dataframe `df` with a column `x_distance`:

```
>>> df["x_distance"].gt(2.5).cumsum()

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: x_distance, dtype: int64
```